# Update object from values in other array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays, BasicItem1 & BasicItem2, I want to update the rate in details array of BasicItem1 with the rate of items in details array of BasicItem2.

For Example change rate of "Almond  Flour" in BasicItem 1 from "1350" to "1250" and for "Egg White 1" from "15" to "225"

BasicItems1:

```
[{
 
  "_id": "5f4249d613ed7a94355aac67",
  "name": "New Macaron sshell",
  "details": [
    {
      "_id": "5f397abb59ad0ba71f27fa93",
      "name": "Egg white 1",
      "baseQuantity": 100,
      "baseUnit": "gm",
      "rate": 15,
      "quantityInRecipe": 121
   

    },
    {
      "_id": "5f397adb59ad0ba71f27fa94",
      "name": "Egg white 2",
      "baseQuantity": 100,
      "baseUnit": "gm",
      "rate": 18,
      "quantityInRecipe": 121,

    },
    {
      "_id": "5f36cdfc875da6156c9a078f",
      "name": "Almound Flour",
      "baseQuantity": 1000,
      "baseUnit": "gm",
      "rate": "1350",
      "quantityInRecipe": "350",
    }
  ]
}]
```

BasicItem2

```
[{
  
  "_id": "5f4249d613ed7a94355aac67",
  "name": "New Macaron sshell",
  "details": [
    {
      "_id": "5f397abb59ad0ba71f27fa93",
      "name": "Egg white 1",
      "baseQuantity": 100,
      "baseUnit": "gm",
      "rate": 225,
      "quantityInRecipe": 121
   

    },
    {
      "_id": "5f397adb59ad0ba71f27fa94",
      "name": "Egg white 2",
      "baseQuantity": 100,
      "baseUnit": "gm",
      "rate": 18,
      "quantityInRecipe": 121,

    },
    {
      "_id": "5f36cdfc875da6156c9a078f",
      "name": "Almound Flour",
      "baseQuantity": 1000,
      "baseUnit": "gm",
      "rate": "1250",
      "quantityInRecipe": "350",
    }
  ]
}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do it

```
let basicItem1Details = basicItem1[0].details
let basicItem2Details = basicItem2[0].details

basicItem1Details.forEach((detail, index) => {
if (detail._id === basicItem2Details[index]._id)
    detail.rate = basicItem2Details[index].rate
})
```

Comment: Hi Nabais THanks for your suggestion./However I want to maintain the structure of BasicItem1 array and update the rates

Comment: my suggestion does not change the structure of BasicItem1, it just updates the values of the rates assuming that BasicItem2 has the same structure. Don't know why you downvoted even though I answered with what you asked